# Replacing page content in Edge

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this to replace all html on the page with the contents of the variable `html`:

```
function rewriteHtml(html) {
    document.open();
    document.write(html);
    document.close();
}
```

It works in both Chrome and Firefox, but I Edge I get the following in the console:

```
Permission denied
```

Why doesn't this work in Edge and how can it be fixed?

Edit:

`html` looks something like this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>"
```

Edit 2:

Also, this function is called asyncronously after the page has been loaded, when the response of an ajax request is received.

Comment: What's `html` ?

Comment: I am wondering why you want to do that. Did you try `document.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: @j08691 the parameter of the function `rewriteHtml`

Comment: @lumio I want to replace the whole document, not only the body

Comment: obviously. But what are you passing to it?

Comment: @j08691 I will make an edit